# Как с помощью PHP отредактировать файл у которого кодировка в Unicode?

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8, unicode, перекодировка

Есть xml файлик с кодировкой Unicode, который был загружен методом POST. Как в нем можно что-то поменять и сохранить для дальнейшего пользование?
simplexml_load_file() говорит, что Unicode не поддерживается. Пришлось раскодировать самому.

Раскодировать получилось, но вот теперь как закодировать?
с кодировками плохо знаком
Пока делаю так:

```
function decode_xml($xml){
    $arr = str_split($xml);
    $text = '';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]|\<|\>|\"|\'|\/|\=|\?|\ |\,|\./", $value)){
            $text .= $value;
        }
    }
    $text = str_replace("Unicode", 'Utf-8', $text);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($text);
    return $xml;
}

function encode_xml($decoded_xml){
    //??
}

if($_FILES){
    $new_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Bloody6\Bloody6\Data\RES\English\SLED\Standard\new2.ckAnimation';
    $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $xml = file_get_contents($tmp); // $xml = ��<�?�x�m�l� �v�e�r�s�i�o�n�=�"�1�.�0�"� �e�n�c�o�d�i�n�g�=�"�U�n�i�c�o�d�e�"�?�>�
    $decoded_xml = decode_xml($xml); //раскодировать $xml
    var_dump($decoded_xml); //Вывести содержимое
    $encoded_xml = encode_xml($decoded_xml); //Закодировать
    file_put_contents($new_path, $encoded_xml); //сохранить
}
```

Пример такого xml: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B58cr0kXJtKIUms1ekxDOEQwNGM

Comment: а обязательно кодировать обратно?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Ответ оказался просто не указывать кодировку...-.-

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
$encoded_xml =  mb_convert_encoding($encoded_xml, "UTF-8", "auto");
```

Если в итоге нужна windows-1251 вместо UTF-8, соотвественно нужно поменять это значение

Comment: *Неужели* неясно, что ему не нужна ни windows-1251, ни UTF-8?

Comment: Вариант mb_convert_encoding($decoded_xml, "Unicode", "Utf-8") вроде бы работает.
Но в хедере не меняет encoding на Unicode.
�e�n�c�o�d�i�n�g�=�"�U�t�f�-�8�"

А если перед этим поменять через str_replace, то возвращает пустую строку

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev не думаю что понимаю нюансы вашей задачи, но может это поможет:  `header("Content-type: text/html; Charset=utf-8");`

Answer (score -2):

Для кодирования есть например Класс 
https://paulferrett.com/2009/encoding-an-object-in-xml-with-php/

Сохраняем рядом со скриптом, например с именем `xmlencoder.php`

```
function encode_xml($decoded_xml){
require ('xmlencoder.php');
$result=XML::encodeObj($decoded_xml);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Да не нужно ему раскодировать. Что ж вы все читаете через одно место?

Comment: У него нет проблем с кодировкой.

Comment: Ну нету, так нету ), вот вариант

Comment: Для того чтобы создать XML в PHP, не нужны никакие сторонние библиотеки. А для того чтобы написать ответ, одного желания недостаточно. Надо еще понять, о чем был вопрос.

Comment: Нужно закодировать в юникод

Answer (score -3):

```
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
if ($l > 0) {
    $ret = array();
    $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i += $l) {
        $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
    }
    return $ret;
}
return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

}

Comment: Вы издеваетесь что ли? Это-то здесь к чему?

Comment: это функци которая перекодирует тебе файл побуквенно, достаточно представить свой вайл в виде строки.

Comment: ты по-английски понимаешь? Можешь прочитать, что написано в названии функции?

Comment: строка расскладывается на уникод это перевод тебе

Comment: неправильный перевод. садись, два.

Comment: раскалывать
split, crack, split up, clove, cleave, splinter
разбивать
break up, break, divide, split, smash, shatter
расщепить
split, splinter

Comment: не вижу здесь слова п е р е к о д и р о в а т ь